# How to rank functions in increasing order

Tags: algorithms

[image: How to rank these functions.]

I mean I could just start putting values in each function and arrange them according to their corresponding values. But is there a better way of doing this.

Comment: Putting in values might not work. The problem is you need to rank them for *asymptotic* behavior which may only happen as $n$ approaches infinity.